# LLDB: Couldn't IRGen expression

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

When I'm running a unit test and want to debug something, I set a breakpoint and type for instance "po myVariable". The response I get from LLDB is:

> error: Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error

Example:

I have the smallest little unit test defined here:

```
class MyExampleTests: XCTestCase {
    func testLLDB() {
        let world = "World"
        print("Breakpoint goes here")
        print("Hello \(world)")
    }
}
```

I set my breakpoint in "Breakpoint goes here", and when I run, I do 'po world':

> (lldb) po world 
> error: Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error

Any suggestions to how I can make it evaluate my expression instead?

Comment: That's not enough information to give a useful answer.  Can you give an example of this failing?

Comment: Edited with example above

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question? I'm facing the very same problem.

Comment: File write privilege is required for some files/folder. I do not know which object exactly requires the privilege, so I have set it recursively. On instance, to give all privileges for all users, do the following: `sudo chmod -R 777 /base_path_to_swift/swift_folder`.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420272/error-couldnt-irgen-expression-no-additional-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using **CocoaPods**, this may apply to you. There are two things to make sure of.

### Gotcha 1: Make sure you have not added `pod` dependencies to your Test target(s) in your `Podfile`:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  project 'MyApp'

  pod 'Alamofire'
  # ... other pods ...

end

target 'MyAppTests' do
  project 'MyApp'
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Do not add your main app pods here
  # You can use pods for writing your test cases though (e.g. mocks)
end
```

In my case I had quite a few frameworks and at least one of them was using binaries and caused LLDB to freak out if I added it to my test target.

As a side note/tip, if you need to use any dependencies from within your app, you need to change the runtime behavior of your main app via launch arguments instead of doing things in your testing code. (This is where I strayed from the path and it caused me problems.) You can do this by adding this to your test file:

```
# When you launch your app (e.g. in `setUpWithError()`)
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments = ["testing-enabled"]
app.launch()
```

and then in your main app code (e.g. in `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`):

```
#if DEBUG
if CommandLine.arguments.contains("testing-enabled") {
    configureAppForTesting()
}
#endif
```

The `#if DEBUG` is not necessary but it's good practice to not ship code that will not be executed in the published app.

### Gotcha 2: If you have custom build configurations, make sure your tests run in `Debug` mode.

For example, if we have created a build config called `App Store` based on `Release` and a test config based on `Debug`, then we need to do the following in our `Podfile`:

```
target 'MyApp' do # do it for MyAppTests also!
  project 'MyApp', 'App Store' => :release, 'Test' => :debug

  # ... pod dependencies, etc.
end
```

Without this setting, your dependencies will be built using the default iOS config which is a `Release` type of configuration (with compiler optimizations for both [Swift](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/itcaec37c2a6?sub=dev076ec5661) and [GCC](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/itcaec37c2a6?sub=dev80f5ad208) that the debugger won't like).

Finally, make sure that your scheme's Test mode is set to use the proper build configuration (in this case `Test`) as in the screenshot below.

[image: Xcode scheme config screen]

Comment: For posterity, the version of CocoaPods I am using is 1.9.1 and Xcode 11.4. Syntax and features might change in the future...

Answer (score 50):

I was having the same issue using Carthage frameworks, and got the LLDB debugger working again by deleting the *Carthage* folder in the project root and forcing Carthage to rebuild the frameworks from source:

```
carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

Comment: Clearing out the `Carthage/Build` folder and rebuilding the dependencies helped me as well.

Comment: That's a workaround, but if you use a lot of dependencies, this can take a lot of time. I'm still searching for a better solution.

Comment: Thank you, it just worked. Maybe you can explain what is the magic behind `--no-use-binaries` option?

Comment: @pjuzeliunas Carthage by default looks up to see if there are prebuilt frameworks (binaries) available to download, so that it doesn't have to build them locally on your machine.

The problem is that those prebuilt frameworks don’t support step-by-step debugging, so the debugging fails unless you build them locally.

Answer (score 44):

You are likely getting this error because you are setting a breakpoint in another project/framework/module.

Instead of `po world`, the quickest solution is to use the following command:

```
fr v world
```

Comment: Not sure that this is the reason we get this error. but the workaround is working, +1.

Comment: Not sure if I should run the command posted by Jonathan Cabrera, but I tried 
`fr v world` instead of `po world` and it worked!!

Comment: What's the difference between "po", "vo" and "fr v"? When will you use one or the other?

Comment: @ReimondHill Good question! My best advice is to read about each one. Checkout this WWDC video for a good place to start: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/429/ -- also, when you're in the debugger, try using `po` if that doesn't work try `p`, then finally try `fr v`.

Answer (score 10):

**edit:**

Since this answer gets some attention, please note that it describes just a quick fix.
If you encounter the problem frequently, check the other answers for a more permanent solution.
<strike>For me, cleaning the build folder did the trick.</strike>  
Edit 2: Cleaning doesn't help in some cases, `carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` always does for me.

**original answer:**

I have a quick and dirty solution that makes this work.

- select the first accessible frame in your debug navigator, usually `main`[image]
- type something in the debugger, for example `po self`
- select the original frame in the debug navigator and **execute your command, it should work now**

I don't know why it works, but it does for me. I just found out by chance.
I'd be interested to hear an explanation from somebody with more insights (I am using Carthage in my project).

Comment: This is crazy. Thank you for the post. This worked for me Xcode Version 11.5.

Comment: worked in xcode 14.3

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I just restarted Xcode, and it's good :)

Comment: This is the most underrated answer, have a point... +1 (and SO AI filters out kudos, imagine my shock)

Comment: not really. I upgrade from 13.5 to 13.6 Xcode, still the error. I think just restarting Xcode is less relevant.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with netx command:
Depend where you have install swift, in my case is in /opt/swift/

```
sudo chmod 644 /opt/swift-3.1.1/usr/lib/swift/CoreFoundation/*
```

Comment: This should be accepted. It''s a pity that this valuable answer wasn't given the respect it deserves!

Comment: Seems like Swift is no longer installed in /opt/

Comment: Anyone found the new Swift location?

Comment: @tzuer Swift on Xcode 10 is in `/usr/bin/swift`. You can find its location by typing `which swift` in a terminal

Comment: So which should be the command now? `sudo chmod 644 /usr/bin/swift/?` The answer applies `chomod 644` to all files inside the `CoreFoundation` of the current swift version. Do someone know where `CoreFoundation` is?

Comment: What is "netx command"? Why does changing the mode of the entire CoreFoundation directory fix the "Couldn't IRGen expression" error?

Answer (score 1):

CocoaPods Binary (https://github.com/leavez/cocoapods-binary) was causing this problem for me. Ended up removing it to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem because of the `Instabug` framework.

If you can't find a solution then you should export the LLDB logs by running the `log enable lldb expr -f /some/path/to/save/logs` command in the debugger and check for failures in that file because that's what helped me.

Also, you should file a bug report on http://bugs.swift.org/ with the LLDB logs attached to it.